# Reactjs: How to solve ERROR in ./node_modules/@heroicons/react/outline/esm/MenuAlt3Icon.js 19:19-35

Tags: reactjs

I've just updated react-script to 5.0.1. After that, I got error in my @heroicons/react.
The part of errors are:
"
ERROR in ./node_modules/@heroicons/react/outline/esm/MenuAlt3Icon.js 19:19-35
export 'forwardRef' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react' (module has no exports)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@heroicons/react/outline/esm/MenuAlt4Icon.js 4:22-41
export 'createElement' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react' (module has no exports)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@heroicons/react/outline/esm/MenuAlt4Icon.js 12:26-45
export 'createElement' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react' (module has no exports)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@heroicons/react/outline/esm/MenuAlt4Icon.js 19:19-35
export 'forwardRef' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react' (module has no exports)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@heroicons/react/outline/esm/MenuIcon.js 4:22-41
export 'createElement' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react' (module has no exports).
"
Can someone help me why that ?

Comment: Some more context would help us to help you. Can you share some code snippets or commands you ran to encounter this issue? What version of React are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.